# Good patterns for loose coupling in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and while reading documentation so far I can't find any good ways for programming with loose coupling between objects. For majority of languages i know (C++, C#, python, JavaScript) I can manage objects as having 'signals' (notification about something happens/something needed)  and 'slots' (method that can be connected to signal and process notification/do some work). In all mentioned languages I can write something like this:

```
Object1 = new Object1Class();
Object2 = new Object2Class();
Connect( Object1.ItemAdded, Object2.OnItemAdded );
```

Now if `object1` calls/emits `ItemAdded`, the `OnItemAdded` method of `Object2` will be called. Such loose coupling technique is often referred as 'delegates', 'signal-slot' or 'inversion of control'.

Compared to interface pattern, technique mentioned don't need to group signals into some interfaces. Any object's methods can be connected to any delegate as long as signatures match ( C++Qt even extends this by allowing only partial signature match ). So i don't need to write additional interface code for each methods / groups of methods, provide default implementation for interface methods not used etc.

And i can't see anything like this in Java :(. Maybe i'm looking a wrong way?

Comment: Spring Framework (which is written in Java) is based on Inversion of Control. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-dependency-injection

Comment: You are actually describing the Observer pattern. The term "loose coupling" is rather abstract concept and can be achieved in many ways (as well as cannot be achieved under certain circumstances).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at Observable and Observer class in java to achieve signal sort of behavior. The main idea is to make the observer do some action when there is a change in the observable object
Classes are java.util.Observable which you object which has to send the signal needs to extend.

Interface is java.util.Observer which your observer classes should implement to act on the signal

Comment: As far as i understood, if observable has a number of events i will need to write individual 'add observer' for each one and call corresponding observer inside each of such event implementation?

Comment: Not necessarily. The `Observer.update` method has an additional "user data" argument. There you can transmit additional information on what has changed.

Comment: This just moved the problem. Instead of function-to-function connection in one line of code i will need to serialize/deserialize function arguments or use lambdas to somehow encapsulate arguments :(

Answer (score 3):

AspectJ might give you the behavior you're looking for.  I haven't touched it in several years, but I remember it being powerful as hell.  But if you're a Java newbie ... I'm not gonna say "Stay away," because hey, you have to learn sometime.  Just be careful.  As I recall, AspectJ doesn't merely give you enough rope to hang yourself; it gives you enough to hogtie and hang your entire family first.  Including your cats.

Comment: +1 because cats are people too (also because AspectJ is an interesting animal)

Comment: Great explanation for aspect J :-D

Comment: Any hint what exact AspectJ feature can help? As i can see, it supplies quit a number of aspect-oriented programming features O_O.

Comment: Unfortunately, no; it's been too long since I used it to offer detailed hints.

Answer (score 2):

You could find bunch of information about modules coupling, as for java I would distinguish next levels of coupling in language level:

1. Static method dependency – high coupling, user code knows about exact implementation
2. New instance creation dependency (A creates instance of B and uses it's behavior) - high, B can't be substituted
3. Reflection dependency – high coupling, A knows about exact implementation of B
4. Inheritance dependency (class B extends A)– high coupling, any change in parent class affects sub classes
5. Class instance dependency (class A has reference to instance of class B)– medium, user code tight to particular class hierarchy, it's medium since java doesn’t support multiple inheritance
6. Interface instance dependency (class A has reference to instance of interface B)- low, since java supports multiple interface implementation.

Easy way to test your implementation on high coupling is to write tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is:

The "slots" implements some interface, f ex `INotifiable`.
The signaling objects have a list of `INotifiable` objects and a method `void Register(INotifiable n)`.

When you want to signal the slots, loop through the list with all the INotifialbes and invoke the the event method that you define yourself.

Comment: This will required in a very large number of interfaces and setters :(. Is it any ways to minimize an amount of code to write?

Answer (score 1):

You can have one object implement a suitable [`EventListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html) and have the other object  fire such events. See [*Writing Event Listeners*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) for more.