# How do you update a progress bar based on another class changing state?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a game, and I'm trying to implement a health bar which will update every time the player takes damage, I've currently got it set up so that it's in a separate panel in the layout:

```
// menu is the bit with the health bar
ControlPanel menu = new ControlPanel(this);
window.add(menu.getMainPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
// view is the part of the window the game runs in
window.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I've heard that to make it update you can use a changelistener, but I've been having some difficulty getting it to run properly, this is what I've got so far:

```
private JProgressBar healthProgressBar;
private Player player;

public ControlPanel(Game game) {
    player = game.getPlayer();

    healthProgressBar.setString(player.getHealth() + "/100");
    healthProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    healthProgressBar.setValue(player.getHealth());
    healthProgressBar.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int oldHealth = player.getHealth();
            player = (Player) e.getSource();
            if (player.getHealth() != oldHealth) {
                healthProgressBar.setValue(player.getHealth());
            }
        }
    });

public JPanel getMainPanel() {
    return mainPanel;
}
```

It will make the progress bar show up where I want it to, and it will have the value I give it, but it doesn't update when the player takes damage, if anyone has any idea how to make it work that'd be great thanks!

Comment: How? I don't understand. In software engineering, coupling is the degree of interdependence between software modules; a measure of how closely connected two routines or modules are;[1] the strength of the relationships between modules.[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming).

Comment: @FailingCoder: A ChangeListener is a version of the Observer Design Pattern, and so please have a look at [How does the Observer pattern reduce coupling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868384/how-does-the-observer-pattern-reduce-coupling) as well as [Good patterns for loose coupling in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492991/good-patterns-for-loose-coupling-in-java) and [more links](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+using+observer+to+reduce+coupling+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @FailingCoder: Why are you posting links to coupling definitions? I think I know the concept quite well, thank you

Comment: To the original poster -- sorry about going off track in comments. You'll want to create and post a valid [mcve] for best answers without our having to guess, since this will allow us to fully understand your code set up.

Comment: And in fact the code you've posted looks like it could be at risk of throwing a NullPointerException, since we do not see how or if you initialize the healthProgressBar variable.

Comment: Myself, I would allow the Player to be "observable" and allow the Game to attach listeners to the Player and respond to notification on its health property with changes in the JProgressBar

Comment: I don't know it well.... too bad for me. I get your point, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is a somewhat long-winded answer, but I just want to show an example of using listeners to allow for looser coupling and for updating a JProgressBar

Say you had a non-GUI Player object, one that has a String name property and an int health property and that used a property change support to allow listeners to be added. A snippet of this class could look like:

```
class Player {
    public static final String HEALTH = "health"; // the name of the property of interest
    public static final int HEALTH_MIN = 0;
    public static final int HEALTH_MAX = 100;
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private String name;
    int health = 50; // value from 1 to 100

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    // any time this is called, listeners will be notified through the pcSupport object
    public void setHealth(int health) {
        int oldValue = this.health;
        int newValue = health;
        this.health = health;

        // notify observers of change in the HEALTH property
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(HEALTH, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // allow listeners/observers to be added
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    // ....... other methods

}
```

Note the decoupling -- the Player class needs to have no knowledge of what GUI it is being displayed in, what the observers will do with any information that they observe.

Now we put this Player in a simple GUI, a JPanel that has a JSlider that allows us to change the state of the player's health property. A snippet of this class's code could look like:

```
class PlayerPanel extends JPanel {
    private Player player;
    private JSlider healthSlider = new JSlider(Player.HEALTH_MIN, Player.HEALTH_MAX, 0); 

    public PlayerPanel(Player player) {
        this.player = player;

        healthSlider.setValue(player.getHealth());
        healthSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
        healthSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        healthSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        healthSlider.setPaintLabels(true);

        // call method to change the player's health when the slider changes
        healthSlider.addChangeListener(clEvent -> healthChange());

        JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
        namePanel.add(new JLabel("Player Name:"));
        namePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        namePanel.add(new JLabel(player.getName()));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(namePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(healthSlider);
    }

    // ........ other methods


    private void healthChange() {
        player.setHealth(healthSlider.getValue());
    }

    // .......... other methods
}
```

Then in another class, one that has JProgressBars, we can display the player's health in the progressBar, and have a listener update the progressBar when this health changes:

```
// create a Player object
Player player = new Player(playerName);

// create a JProgressBar to show the health
final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(Player.HEALTH_MIN, Player.HEALTH_MAX);
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressBar.setValue(player.getHealth()); // set initial value

// add a PropertyChangeListener to Player to be notified when HEALTH changes
player.addPropertyChangeListener(Player.HEALTH, pcEvent -> setProgress(progressBar, player));
```

And we would update the JProgressBar from the setProgress method:

```
private void setProgress(JProgressBar progressBar, Player player) {
    int health = player.getHealth();
    progressBar.setValue(health);
}
```

---

The whole working example could look like so:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JProgressHealth extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] PLAYER_NAMES = {"John", "Steve", "Frank", "Judy", "Hillary", "Billy"};
    private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public JProgressHealth(Window owner) {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (String playerName : PLAYER_NAMES) {
            Player player = new Player(playerName);
            final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(Player.HEALTH_MIN, Player.HEALTH_MAX);
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBar.setValue(player.getHealth());
            player.addPropertyChangeListener(Player.HEALTH, pcEvent -> setProgress(progressBar, player));            
            JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            titlePanel.add(progressBar);
            titlePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(player.getName()));
            add(titlePanel);

            // create player panels to illustrate how this works
            PlayerPanel playerPanel = new PlayerPanel(player);
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(owner, player.getName(), ModalityType.MODELESS);
            dialog.add(playerPanel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    // make JPanel wider
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int w = 3 * superSize.width;
        int h = superSize.height;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    private void setProgress(JProgressBar progressBar, Player player) {
        int health = player.getHealth();
        progressBar.setValue(health);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Health");

        JProgressHealth mainPanel = new JProgressHealth(frame);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PlayerPanel extends JPanel {
    private Player player;
    private JSlider healthSlider = new JSlider(Player.HEALTH_MIN, Player.HEALTH_MAX, 0); 

    public PlayerPanel(Player player) {
        this.player = player;

        healthSlider.setValue(player.getHealth());
        healthSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
        healthSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        healthSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        healthSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        healthSlider.addChangeListener(clEvent -> healthChange());

        JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
        namePanel.add(new JLabel("Player Name:"));
        namePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        namePanel.add(new JLabel(player.getName()));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(namePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(healthSlider);
    }

    // make JPanel wider
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
        int w = 2 * superSize.width;
        int h = superSize.height;
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }


    private void healthChange() {
        player.setHealth(healthSlider.getValue());
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
}
```

```
class Player {
    public static final int HEALTH_MIN = 0;
    public static final int HEALTH_MAX = 100;
    public static final String HEALTH = "health";
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private String name;
    int health = 50; // value from 1 to 100

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        int oldValue = this.health;
        int newValue = health;
        this.health = health;

        // notify observers of change
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(HEALTH, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String name, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(name, listener);
    }
}
```